# angular components not refreshing on route change (in ui router)

Tags: angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, angular-components

i have described my states like

```
  `.state('community.messaging', {
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
        url: '/messaging',
        abstract: true
    })    
    .state('community.messaging.user', {
        url: '/user/:userId',
        component: 'messagingComponent',
    })`
```

and when i use $state.go("community.messaging.user")
it opens that component, but after change another state back or go to state "community.messaging.user" it not clears previous values in that component controller which i initialised before.
my component is like this

```
import messagingController from "./messaging.controller.js";
export const messagingComponent = 'messagingComponent';
export const messagingComponentOptions = {
templateUrl: './src/app/components/messaging/messaging.html',
controller: ['$scope', '$localStorage', '$rootScope', '$transitions', '$timeout', '$cookies', '$state', '$stateParams', 'communityApi', messagingController],
controllerAs: 'ctrl'}
```

and  contoller is like

```
function messagingController($scope, $localStorage, $rootScope, $sanitize, $transitions, $cookies, $state, $stateParams, communityApi) {
   const self = this;
   self.currentSelectedChatUser = {
        id: $stateParams.userId,
        room: ''
    };
    self.message = '';
    self.chatData = [];
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit('initiate', $stateParams.userId)
        socket.on('privateRoomCreated', function (data) {
           if(`self.currentSelectedChatUser.room == ""`) {
              self.currentSelectedChatUser.room = data.room;
           }
        });
    )}
}
```

first time when i go this state `self.currentSelectedChatUser.room == ""` but when i came again from other state it shows `self.currentSelectedChatUser.room == "someroomid"` in if statement but it should be `self.currentSelectedChatUser.room == ""`;
and if reload browser it sets to `self.currentSelectedChatUser.room == ""`

Answer (score 0):

It's because your controller is not re-initialized each time you change state. You can use the $onInit [hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) to initialize your controller each time you reach it, try :

```
function messagingController($scope, $localStorage, $rootScope, $sanitize, 
 $transitions, $cookies, $state, $stateParams, communityApi) {
   const self = this;
   self.$onInit = function() {
     self.currentSelectedChatUser = {
          id: $stateParams.userId,
          room: ''
     };
   };
   self.message = '';
   self.chatData = [];
   socket.on('connect', function () {
     socket.emit('initiate', $stateParams.userId)
     socket.on('privateRoomCreated', function (data) {
        if(`self.currentSelectedChatUser.room == ""`) {
           self.currentSelectedChatUser.room = data.room;
        }
     });
  )}
}
```